# Define in XSD a list of byte arrays

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

In my DTO I have a variable `List<byte[]> attachmentList` and I would likt to model it in XSD. So far I have:

```
                    <xs:element name="attachmentList" type="AttachmentList">
                    </xs:element>

<!-- more code goes here -->


<!-- List of ByteArrays -->
    <xs:complexType name="AttachmentList">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="documents" type="ByteArray" nillable="true">
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="ByteArray">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="byteArrayElement" type="xs:byte"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Unfortunately, in the class generated by `JAXB` it is then displayed as `protected AttachmentList attachmentList;` , the `AttachmentList` contains `protected ByteArray documents;` and then finally the `ByteArray` class contains `protected List<Byte> byteArrayElement;`, which is also incorrect. How shall I correctly define in `XSD` a list of byte arrays?

Comment: You could have just run the [`schemagen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/schemagen.html) *(Java 8)* command to get the XSD generated for you. Also available in a JAXB download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct type for a `byte[]` is [`xs:base64Binary`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-2-20120405/datatypes.html#base64Binary).

That means the XSD for a field `List<byte[]> attachmentList` should simply be:

```xml
<xs:element name="attachmentList" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

Comment: Oh...of course!  ...and I spent hours trying to figure it out. Thanks a lot! 